# Solving a complex trigonometric problem

Tags: complex-numbers

My question says to find all solutions to $\sin(2z)=5$, I am given that
\begin{equation*}
\text{Equation 1:}\,\,\,\cosh^{-1}5=\frac{1}{2}\ln(5+2\sqrt{6})=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(5-2\sqrt6)
\end{equation*}
and I should solve the equation by using the result
\begin{equation*}
\text{Equation 2:}\,\,\,\sin^{-1}=-i\log[iz+(1-z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}]
\end{equation*}

I've tried playing around with these equations, and the fact that
$\sin (z)=\sin (x)\cosh (y)+i\cos (x)\sinh(y)$
But I can't figure out how to find $z$ in this question

Answer (score 1):

I'll skip a few "but why?" details you should make sure you can work out yourself.  Write $z=x+iy$ with $x,\,y\in\Bbb R$ so $\cos2x\sinh2y=0$, but $\sinh2y\ne0$ because $2z\notin\Bbb R$, so $\cos2x=0$. Hence $\cosh2y=5,\,\sin2x=1$.

Comment: I understand how you got those values, I've rearranged equation 1 as $2y=\cosh^{-1}(5)$ which I believe gives me the imaginary component of $z$, but I'm stumped on how to find the real component

Comment: @anamingo26 I know your question has $2z$; that's where my factors of $2$ come from. Since $2z=-i\ln[5i\pm\sqrt{24}i]$, doing it via equation $2$ requires converting the logarithm's argument to polar form, but it'll work as you guessed. Or if you use my method, each real root of $\sin2x=1$ works.

Comment: Which equation did you pull the $2z=-i\ln[5i\pm \sqrt{24}i]$ from?

Comment: @anamigo26 equation $2$, since $2z=\arcsin5$ is a solution.